# Interactive plot in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, real-time, interactive, jupyter

I am trying to get 'realtime' ploting in Jupyter notebook.
The example can be found [here](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/url/jointlab.upol.cz/machulka/download/_tmp/matplotlib.ipynb). Here is the code:

```
%matplotlib notebook

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl

from random import randint
from time import sleep

from ipywidgets import FloatProgress
from IPython import display

siz = 10
dat = np.zeros((siz, siz))

fig = pl.figure()
axe = fig.add_subplot(111)
img = axe.imshow(dat)

num = 1000

prgBar = FloatProgress(min=0, max=num-1)
display.display(prgBar)

for i in range(num):
    prgBar.value = i
    pos = (randint(0, siz-1), randint(0, siz-1))
    dat[pos] += 1
    img.set_data(dat)
    img.autoscale()
    #sleep(0.01)
```

What I am aiming for is to see how the plot is changing with each itteration.
I also tried set the interactive mod on by pl.ion(), changing backent to inline, calling pl.draw(), but non of it was working. BTW, the progressbar is working just fine...

Thanks Radek

Comment: Have a look at `%matplotlib notebook` which gives you a full interactive backend.

Comment: You will need to make your figure in a different cell than the loop, but otherwise it should work.

Comment: If you look at the link I posted you will see that they are in different cels.

Answer (score 1):

The following code should do the trick:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from random import randint
from time import sleep

from ipywidgets import FloatProgress
from IPython.display import display, clear_output

siz = 10
dat = np.zeros((siz, siz))

fig = plt.figure()
axe = fig.add_subplot(111)
img = axe.imshow(dat)

num = 1000

prgBar = FloatProgress(min=0, max=num-1)
display(prgBar)

for i in range(num):
    clear_output(wait = True)
    prgBar.value = i
    pos = (randint(0, siz-1), randint(0, siz-1))
    dat[pos] += 1
    img.set_data(dat)
    img.autoscale()
    display(fig)
```

I changed the for loop creating the image on each step and also imported `clear_output` to clean the cell output on each step.

Comment: This does work, however: 1) you have to change matplotlib magic to inline, 2) it creates second plot (so the first one can be omitted), but mainly, 3) it is terribly slow (I guess because you are redrawing everything). So even though it works, it does not feel like the optimal way...

Comment: 1) Yes :-(, 2) I modified the code to improve this, 3) I modifed the loop to improve performance around 30/40% but it is slow. I'm sorry but I don't know a better way to do it in the notebook. In the end you have to `display` the image and you are displaying 1000 images and communicating the front and the back end 1000 times. The `display` step takes around 130ms and the rest of the code in the loop takes around 10ms more so each step in the loop is around 140ms. IF you find a better way just post it here ;-)